# How to get/calculate a Vue components source code?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using Vue 3 and would like to convert my Vue component to the equivalent source code (Similar to Storybook).

From what I've read it's possible to use `@vue/compiler-sfc` but I have an error occur.

```
const parsedComponent = parse(MyComponent).descriptor;

// Extract template, script, and style
const template = parsedComponent.template ? parsedComponent.template.content : '';
const script = parsedComponent.script ? parsedComponent.script.content : '';
const style = parsedComponent.styles.length ? parsedComponent.styles[0].content : '';

console.log('Template:', template);
console.log('Script:', script);
console.log('Style:', style);
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: currentInput.slice is not a function
    at getSlice (@vue_compiler-sfc.js?v=9c64ce65:17942:23)
    at Object.ontext (@vue_compiler-sfc.js?v=9c64ce65:17585:12)
    at Tokenizer.handleTrailingData (@vue_compiler-sfc.js?v=9c64ce65:1908:16)
    at Tokenizer.finish (@vue_compiler-sfc.js?v=9c64ce65:1890:10)
    at Tokenizer.parse (@vue_compiler-sfc.js?v=9c64ce65:1869:10)
    at baseParse (@vue_compiler-sfc.js?v=9c64ce65:18235:15)
    at Object.parse$8 [as parse] (@vue_compiler-sfc.js?v=9c64ce65:24158:10)
    at parse$7 (@vue_compiler-sfc.js?v=9c64ce65:25039:24)
    at extractComponentInfo (utils.js:6:33)
    at Proxy.created (Example.vue?t=1707177222801:15:27)
extractComponentInfo @ utils.js:15
created @ Example.vue?t=1707177222801:15
callWithErrorHandling @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:1652
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:1660
callHook @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:5060
applyOptions @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:4979
finishComponentSetup @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:9157
setupStatefulComponent @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:9080
setupComponent @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:9009
mountComponent @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7339
processComponent @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7305
patch @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:6771
mountChildren @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7019
processFragment @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7235
patch @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:6745
componentUpdateFn @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7449
run @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:431
instance.update @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7573
setupRenderEffect @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7583
mountComponent @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7351
processComponent @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7305
patch @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:6771
mountChildren @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7019
processFragment @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7235
patch @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:6745
componentUpdateFn @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7449
run @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:431
instance.update @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7573
setupRenderEffect @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7583
mountComponent @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7351
processComponent @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:7305
patch @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:6771
render2 @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:8094
mount @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:5368
app.mount @ vue.js?v=9c64ce65:11059
(anonymous) @ index.ts:5
Show 33 more frames
Show less
Example.vue:20
```

I can't figure out how this is done. The alternative could be to actually create the component and step through it's children and properties (possibly?).

Is there a simple method of getting/calculating the source code required to create a component?

Comment: `MyComponent` is already parsed. If you want to parse it - you should read the `.vue` file directly through the filesystem and then feed it to `parse()`

Comment: @IVOGELOV How would something like Storybook handle this? You don't pass them the file, they take the component and will output a preview. It makes it seem more like they have created an instance of the component and extracted information out of it?
I just want to import a component and extract the template section out of it in a similar fashion.

Comment: This looks like XY problem. As said, MyComponent is already parsed. parse() would work for a string with the contents of .vue file, but this is what .vue loader already did. Consider explaining which kind of info you need from a comp exactly

Comment: I would like to get the template section from MyComponent without directly reading the file.

Comment: You can not get the template without directly reading the file - when you get a component instance, it is already a JavaScript function which renders in imperative way the declaratively specified template. Vue components do not support reflection in the same sense as JAVA does so you can not ask the component instance to generate its own template based on its render function. Compilation is a one-way process only.

Comment: Storybook does not show you the template of components - it actually instantiates the components and you get their live behavior. And eventually examples how to include these components into other (parent) components.